# LWC @wire change 'this' context

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, wire, context

I have a problem with my code

```
export default class PdmNewModalPlist extends LightningElement {
    @api objectName;
    @api fieldName;
    @api apiName;
    @api recordTypeId;
    @track obj;
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { 
        recordTypeId:'$recordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: { 
            fieldApiName: *this.fieldName*, 
            objectApiName: *this.objectName*
        }
    })
    PicklistValues;
}
```

In marked places i want to call variables but that's don't work. Propably because 'this' context shows function not document. How i can change 'this' context or make this function works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'This' context isn't a problem here, The main problem is an execution order. @Sfdcfox's solution won't work because values will be 'undefined'. The solution that works for me is creating an object in connectedCallback function and pass that object to @wire function

```
 connectedCallback(){
        this.obj = { fieldApiName: this.fieldName, objectApiName: this.objectName};
     }

 @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId:'$recordTypeId' , fieldApiName: '$obj' })
                                PicklistValues;
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, although I'm not sure why it is so.  The getPicklistValues adapter should work just like the other ones, but for some reason, you do have to set a new variable in connectedCallback in order for this to work

Answer (score 3):

You want to use reactive variables:

```
    @wire(getPicklistValues, { 
        recordTypeId:'$recordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: { 
            fieldApiName: '$fieldName', 
            objectApiName: '$objectName'
        }
    })
    PicklistValues;
```

You can read more in [Understand the Wire Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about).

Comment: still not work. When i consolLog picklistValue i get:                                                  handler: de

membrane: {valueDistortion: function, valueMutated: function, valueObserved: function, valueIsObservable: function, objectGraph: WeakMap}

originalTarget: Object

data: undefined

error: fp {status: 403, body: {message: "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.", statusCode: 403, errorCode: "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS"}, headers: {}